# How to change label size in python networkx

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx, legend

My sample code and result plot are as below.

I would like to change node size in upper right legend.

To be specific, I'm trying to make equal size of each node in legend.

There's no problem the size of nodes in axes.

[image]

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# define nodes, node types, and color range

nodes = list('abcdefghijkl')
nodeTypes = ['foo','bar','baz']
nodeColors = ['r', 'b', 'k']

# assign each node a type and color via a dictionaries
nodeTypeDict = dict(zip(nodeTypes, [nodes[:4],nodes[4:8],nodes[8:]]))
nodeColorDict = dict(zip(nodeTypes, nodeColors))
nodePos = dict(zip(nodes,[(np.random.random(),np.random.random()) 
                                        for i in range(len(nodes))]))

# generate the graph
g = nx.Graph()
g.add_nodes_from(nodes)

# create image canvas and axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(6,6))

# iterate each nodetype, changing colors and labels of the nodes
for nt, i in [('foo', 10), ('bar', 1), ('baz',20)]:
    # choose nodes and color for each iteration
    nlist = nodeTypeDict[nt]
    ncolor = nodeColorDict[nt]
    print(ncolor)
    # draw the graph
    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(g, 
                           pos=nodePos,
                           nodelist=nlist,
                           ax=ax, 
                           node_color=ncolor,
                           node_size = i,
                           label= nt)  # the label for each iteration is 
                                      # the node type
ax.legend(scatterpoints=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix the size for each legend item.

```
legend = ax.legend(scatterpoints=1)
for item in legend.legendHandles:
    item._sizes = [40]
```